# I used python library of rpaframework to to open browser using function open_available browser

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, rpa, robocode

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "C:\Users\MinMagar\AppData\Local\quickrpa\robot\a68f6186-1d0b-407f-b92d-fe0f04291f4f\QuickShorts-NewsScraper\app\sites\NavBharatTimes.py", line 67, in main
    self.setup()
  File "C:\Users\MinMagar\AppData\Local\quickrpa\robot\a68f6186-1d0b-407f-b92d-fe0f04291f4f\QuickShorts-NewsScraper\app\sites\NavBharatTimes.py", line 105, in setup
    self.selenium.open_available_browser(url = self.site_url, maximized=True, alias="scrapper", download=True)
  File "c:\ProgramData\robocorp\ht\9daf67f_5a1fac3_13fbd287\lib\site-packages\RPA\Browser\common.py", line 36, in wrapper
    return super_func(*args, headless=headless, **kwargs)
  File "c:\ProgramData\robocorp\ht\9daf67f_5a1fac3_13fbd287\lib\site-packages\RPA\Browser\Selenium.py", line 531, in open_available_browser
    raise BrowserNotFoundError(msg)
RPA.Browser.Selenium.BrowserNotFoundError: Failed to start a browser:
```

- Chrome: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
- Firefox: maximum recursion depth exceeded
- Edge: maximum recursion depth exceeded

I was trying to open browser using rpaframework using funtion open_available_browser. Driver perfectly work on other open browser function such as open_browser but not in open_available_browser.
Browser in not opening in  above case all supported browsers : Chrome, Firefox and Edge